# Chart object delete error

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing the clear function. Whenever there is no Chart Object to delete, it pop out an error. Is there a way to make it error free? When it does not have a chart to clear, it just leave it the same as it is.

```
Sheet6.ChartObjects.Delete
```

Comment: Write a conditional statement that only deletes chart objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is this...

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheet6.ChartObjects.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```